# uwp scrollViewer set limits

Tags: xaml, scroll, grid, uwp, scrollviewer

I'm working with a Grid and a ScrollViewer in a UWP page, where each row represents a Shelf. I have N rows, but I need to set the limits of the ScrollViewer between the end of the first row and the beginning of the last one, because they are out of the screen (I only have these rows so when the user scrolls until the limits I don't want him to see the background, but an empty row instead).

Is there any way to scpecify an upper and a bottom limits for the ScrollViewer?

This is the XAML where I define these elements:

```
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Name="MyScrollViewer">
    <Grid Name="MyGrid" Tapped="HideOptionMenu">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The rows are added dynamically on runtime, so the number of rows is not always the same. Also, the height of each row changes when I resize the screen.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to set the limits of a ScrollViewer.

One way you can achieve what you want is to put the overscroll rows into the first and last grid rows and translate them outside the bounds of the ScrollViewer so that they will be visible when overscrolling.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Top overscroll row -->
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Orange" Stroke="Black">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform Y="-100"/>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>

        <!-- Bottom overscroll row -->
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Orange" Stroke="Black">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform Y="100"/>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="7" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

It feels a bit clumsy using a Grid for what really is a StackPanel/ListView layout, but since I don't know specifics about your UI, I assume you have a reason for doing so.